# Storing facebook user birthday to mysql

Tags: mysql, facebook, codeigniter, date

I am using Codeigniter and mysql.

I got the facebook user birthday with 01/23/1999  format

and I got date YYYY/M/D format in mysql table.

How can I insert it?

I tried but I got 0000/00/00 and also tried str_to_date() but no idea why codeigniter cannot pass it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$datetoputinmysql = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($facebookvariable))

Comment: Thanks, same answer. Works as well. But you are late, nvm. I will accept yours because u got lower points. LOL

Answer (score 2):

```
$mysql_date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime('01/23/1999'));
```

Comment: This is correct based on his question, but doesn't a mysql date field use YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: Yes, but I suspect they made the field a varchar. It's a typical new programmer mistake.

Comment: @JohnConde No, i have already said i got a date format in mysql. I using date field.

Comment: Then my answer is 'more correct' although we basically said the same thing, it's just how you want to format the date. See here for formatting options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php (although pretty sure you will want to use 'Y-m-d')

Comment: @vzhen that's is very kind of you!